# MySQL crashed because of the large number of requests

Tags: mysql

I often began to fall down mysql.
I recorded a large number of requests:

```
| 243751 | user | localhost | database | Query | 985 | Sending data | SELECT option_name, option_value FROM wp_options WHERE autoload = 'yes' |
```

How to identify the problem and fix it?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL shouldn't crash because of queries like those, but it could feel like it does because your site won't work.

I'd first run

```
SELECT option_name, length(option_value) FROM wp_options WHERE autoload = 'yes' ORDER BY length(option_value) DESC;
```

to see if some option has accumulated a large value (I've seen wp-cron entries grow very large in one release ~2 years back).

Also check how many options will be automatically loaded:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM wp_options WHERE autoload = 'yes';
```

Those are usually a few hundred, if it's a very large number, investigate further.

If both these queries don't show anything weird, you may want to look into MySQL itself. Is the RAM on your machine exhausted and (slow) SWAP is being used? Is there a faulty hard disk and re-reads are timing out?

Comment: The first request was issued by: http://joxi.ru/a2XzXPlTykoblr   . 
the second request issued the following quantity: 26056.  Memory on the server is used only 5 percent of the total

Comment: 26k options looks like a lot. Maybe output the results for `SELECT option_name FROM wp_options WHERE autoload = 'yes' ORDER BY option_name;` and scroll through that list. I'm pretty sure you will find patterns. Maybe you're using transients heavily? If you find lots of options with names that start with `_transient_` or `_site_transient_`, those might be the problem. They're usually safe to delete (but make sure you have a backup in any case before performing database operations).

Comment: Records found a lot, but the question, but `_transient_` no.
What to do in this case?

Comment: Look for similar records and figure out where they're coming from. Since the list is ordered, you should be able to quickly scroll through it and see parts of the names being repeated.

Comment: Thank you. I found many records of this type: `_transient_0508d1455aa8d2a05e684f5f7e4c1a8a`. I will delete

Comment: I deleted the transient.
Today, again fell mysql. Here is what was today:   `11022 database       localhost user      20888  Query  Waiting INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('_transient_timeout_instantarticles_mod_19499', '1514767515', 'no') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `option_name` = VALUES(`option_name`), `option_value` = VALUES(`o`

Comment: What other statements can you see in MySQL? This sounds less like a WP problem and more like a problem with MySQL itself. Is the server swapping?   Is there very high risk IO?

Comment: Here's what else outputs: http://joxi.ru/Drlg0kKf4zqnXA     What is it ?: "Is there very high risk IO?"

Comment: Damn auto-correct. I meant to ask about disk IO ;). `iotop` should give you some values. Those queries all look simple and should be dealt with quickly. Is the server running at a normal speed otherwise?

Comment: now these requests are not displayed at all, now others are active, usual for Wordpress.
In io there is nothing abnormal

Comment: I'm afraid this is about as far as we can go with remote debugging. I don't believe that it is related to WP. If you're on a virtual machine, the host performance might be very bad at times, leading to very slow read/write speeds on disk, but that's just speculation. You might want to ask on on [DBA.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com), they can probably provide better feedback and avenues for research.

Comment: I have a separate server. Thanks, I will write on dba